# How to reduce loading time of models made with three.js editor?

Tags: graphics, three.js, 3d, loading, 3d-model

I created a 3D model made of 160 objects (cubes with different textures) using the three.js editor, then I exported the model and used THREE.ObjectLoader() to import it in a scene I'm working on (as explained here https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/ObjectLoader).

However I noticed that loading the file and display the model on screen takes quite some time. What can I do to reduce this waiting time?

I thought maybe it'd be a good idea to merge some of the geometries of the model, but I can't figure out how to do it on a model created using the three.js editor.

Comment: Without more details about the file, we'll have to guess. ;) Often, the total size of your textures will block rendering for a while... how big are they? You could also try exporting to something supported outside three.js (like GLB), import that to Blender 2.80+, and merge the meshes. But if the meshes all have different textures that will be harder.